# Is it possible to use bind with non standard client side event in Jquery

Tags: jquery, asp.net, events, ajaxcontroltoolkit, unobtrusive-javascript

For example this [AsyncFileUpload](http://www.asp.net/ajaxLibrary/AjaxControlToolkitSampleSite/AsyncFileUpload/AsyncFileUpload.aspx), there is an event "OnClientUploadComplete"

Can i do something like

```
$("#ctl00_MainContent_AsyncFileUpload1_ctl02")
.bind("OnClientUploadComplete", function () {  alert("test"); 
 })
```

> ```
> <ajaxToolkit:AsyncFileUpload  OnClientUploadComplete="uploadComplete" 
>     runat="server" ID="upload"
> Width="400px" UploaderStyle="Modern" CompleteBackColor="White" UploadingBackColor="#CCFFFF"
> ThrobberID="imgLoader" OnUploadedComplete="AsyncFileUpload1_UploadedComplete" 
>     OnClientUploadStarted = "uploadStarted" />
>  <asp:Image ID="imgLoader" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/images/loader.gif" /><br /><br />
>  <img id = "imgDisplay" alt="" src="" style = "display:none"/>
> ```
>
> ```
> $addHandler($("#<%=upload.ClientID %>"), 'uploadComplete', (function () { alert("test"); }));
>
>
> function uploadStarted() {
>     $get("imgDisplay").style.display = "none";
> }
> function uploadComplete(sender, args) {
>     var imgDisplay = $get("imgDisplay");
>     imgDisplay.src = "images/loader.gif";
>     imgDisplay.style.cssText = "";
>     var img = new Image();
>     img.onload = function () {
>         imgDisplay.style.cssText = "height:100px;width:100px";
>         imgDisplay.src = img.src;
>     };
>     img.src = "<%=ResolveUrl(UploadFolderPath) %>" + args.get_fileName();
> } </script>
> ```

Comment: It depends on how the event is raised within the code of the control.

Comment: @rsplak I have tried it and it didn't work. don't sure if it is not possible or i did it the wrong way.

Comment: Show how you tried to use `OnClientUploadComplete` property

Answer (score 0):

No, you cannot do this.

Custom events in the AJAX Control Toolkit are implemented outside of the browser's event system. See [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb398781.aspx) for details.

You will have to use the `add_uploadComplete()` method provided by the component:

```
$find("yourBehaviorID").add_uploadComplete(function() {
    alert("test").
});
```

Where `yourBehaviorID` is the `BehaviorID` of your extender (defaulting to the `ClientID` of the extended control).

Comment: how come is the .addadd_uploadComplete(), how do you find it ?

Comment: @Sarawut, in the [source code](http://ajaxcontroltoolkit.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/1014bf767f65#Server%2fAjaxControlToolkit%2fAsyncFileUpload%2fAsyncFileUpload.pre.js). All the AJAX Control Toolkit's components expose custom events that way, actually.

Comment: Did you pass the right behavior id? Can you update your question with the part of the page markup where the `AsyncFileUpload` extender is defined, so we can double-check?

Comment: @Sarawut, try using `$find()` and `add_uploadComplete()` instead of `$addHandler()`. The latter can only be used to register "standard" DOM events, not custom events IIRC, and I'm pretty sure its first argument should be a DOM element, not an id selector.